# Xamarin.iOS: How to add query parameters to HTML file with NSUrl?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have built a Xamarin.Forms app with a Hybrid Web View using this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview). My Hybrid Web View uses a local HTML file which contains JavaScript which renders the page.

Now my local HTML file takes in query parameters through JavaScript and I have successfully implemented this in my Xamarin.Android project using this snippet located in the Hybrid View Renderer:

```
if (e.NewElement != null)
{
    Control.AddJavascriptInterface(new JSBridge(this), "jsBridge");
    Control.LoadUrl($"file:///android_asset/Content/{Element.Uri}");
}
```

Where `Element.Uri` contains `MyFile.Html?x=1&y=2&z=3` as a string. This loads my local HTML page perfectly.

I can't get the same success in my Xamarin.iOS project. For my Xamarin.iOS project, I am using this snippet, located in the iOS Hybrid View Renderer, to try and load my local HTML file:

```
if (e.NewElement != null)
{
    string fileName = Path.Combine(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, string.Format("Content/{0}", Element.Uri));
    NSUrl nsUrl = new NSUrl(filename, false);
    Control.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest (nsUrl));
}
```

When I run my app, the page renders nothing and no exceptions are thrown. I have debugged my code and noticed that `nsUrl.AbsoluteString` contains `file:///path/to/MyFile.html%3Fx=1&y=2&z=3`where the `?` at the start of the query parameters have been encoded to `%3F`. I suspect this is the problem.

Is there a way to pass query parameters to a local HTML file in Xamarin.iOS? Or am I taking this approach the wrong way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSUrlComponents` with an array of `NSUrlQueryItem` elements to construct your `NSUrl`:

#### Example:

```
using (var contentBase = NSUrl.FromFilename(Path.Combine(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, "WebSite")))
using (var url = new NSUrlComponents
{
    Scheme = "file",
    Host = "localhost",
    Path = Path.Combine(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, "WebSite", "index.html"),
    QueryItems = new[] { new NSUrlQueryItem("x", "1"), new NSUrlQueryItem("y", "2"), new NSUrlQueryItem("z", "3") }
}.Url)
{
    webView.LoadFileUrl(url, contentBase);
}
```

#### Resulting `NSUrl` AbsoluteString output:

```
file://localhost/.../some.ios.app/WebSite/index.html?x=1&y=2&z=3
```